# OpenGL: missing shadows on the cube shape

Tags: opengl, shadows, light

Why the shadows are gone from unlighted faces of my cube shape when I am using arrays of:

```
vertices[] 
indices[] 
colors[] 
normals[] 
texcoords[] 
// and draw them by
glDrawElements();
```

But when I use:

```
glBegin(...);
 glVertex3f(...);
glEnd(...);
```

The shadows are ok. 
Here you got an image of what is happening: [image: IMG]

My light is set as below:

```
glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glColorMaterial( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);        
glHint (GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

GLfloat AmbientLight[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0,0, 1.0};
GLfloat DiffuseLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1,0, 1.0};
GLfloat SpecularLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat Shininess[] = { 90.0 };
GLfloat Emission[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, Shininess);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, Emission);
```

Comment: What shadows? Neither image shows anything that resembles shadows, just different shading for one cube face and the circle-like object.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a call to

```
glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
```